# Structs and initializing arrays

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have been trying to work out how to use structs with arrays and do not understand how to initialise the first three items of the array as in seen in the code. I am also getting errors when trying to print or scan in values of the array as it is saying that they are all integers even though I have declared them as strings/characters. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLEN 100

typedef struct{
  char name;          <<have now changed all to [MAXLEN+1]
  char surname;       <<
  char UUN;           <<
  char department;    <<  
  char gender;
  int age;
} student_t;


int main(void){
  student_t details[5];
  int i, n;

  details[0].name = "John";           <<should all the '=' be ',' instead?
  details[0].surname = "Bishop";      <<do not understand how to initialize
  details[0].UUN = "s1234";
  details[0].department = "Inf";
  details[0].gender = 'm';
  details[0].age = 18;

  details[1].name = "Lady";
  details[1].surname = "Cook";
  details[1].UUN = "s2345";
  details[1].department = "Eng";
  details[1].gender = 'f';
  details[1].age = 21;

  details[2].name = "James";
  details[2].surname = "Jackson";
  details[2].UUN = "s3456";
  details[2].department = "Eng";
  details[2].gender = 'm';
  details[2].age = 17;

  for(i = 3; i < 6; i++){
    printf("Enter first name second name UUN department gender age: \n");
    scanf(" %s %s %s %s %c %d", details[i].name, details[i].surname, details[i].UUN, details[i].department, details[i].gender, details[i].age);
  }

  for(n = 0; n < 6;n++){
    printf("details: %s", details[n].name);
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your struct members are just individual `char` objects. How do you expect each of your strings to fit into a single `char`?

Comment: Here's a hint: char can only hold one character. You want to hold strings. How might you do that?

Comment: yeah done that but every time I declare it as a string errors come up in scanf saying it is char** and expected a string. left it as shown as for some reason it was the only way to stop it

Answer (score 0):

You have to put every string with its size.

`char name;` should be `char name[30]; //for example`

And you should use `strcpy` (from string.h) to put a char array (string) at the variables.

```
details[0].name = "John"; should be  strcpy(details[0].name,"John");
```